# Reverse the order of thumbnail images in media.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, php

**Situation:**

In my store when a product has more then one image, the (Product)page shows the images in a jQuery slideshow. The code for this slider is created from the thumbnails in media.phtml with the following snippet:

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <ul id="productSlider">

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php
        if (($filterClass = $this->getGalleryFilterHelper()) && ($filterMethod = $this->getGalleryFilterMethod()) && !Mage::helper($filterClass)->$filterMethod($_product, $_image)):
            continue;
        endif;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" rel="media" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(800); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(265); ?>"
                     width="265" height="265" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Problem:**

The thumbnails are presented in reverse order, resulting in the main image always being displayed last (and out of sight).

**Question:**

What would I need to change to reverse the order in the thumbnail generation so the "main" image gets displayed first?

Comment: Did you have a look at [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)?

Answer (score 1):

if `$this->getGalleryImages()` returns a collection you can just transform it to an array, reverse it and iterated it.

```
$images = array();
foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
    $images[] = $image;
}
$images = array_reverse($images);

foreach ($images as $image) {
.....//your display here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try to change the php for loop to be

```
<?php $i=0; foreach(array_reverse($this->getGalleryImages()) as $_image): ?>
```

or

```
<?php $i=0; foreach(array_reverse($this->getGalleryImages()->getData()) as $_image): ?>
```

if getGalleryImages() returns a collection

but that would be kind of a hack.  That may meet your immediate needs however.  In general, you should post the code for getGalleryImages() so we can see if the problem lies there or in possibly in your DB.

Comment: Pretty sure `getGalleryImages` will return a collection, not an array so this probably won't work.

Comment: If it returns a collection, you can use array_reverse($collection->toArray())

Answer (score 0):

Well you must to modily the loop of php array:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach(array_reverse($this->getGalleryImages()->getData()) as $_image): ?>
```

Good Job